# Laravel API route - exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm making a Blog for school on my portfolio website, now I'm doing this in VueJS and Laravel and for this I need API routes.
Now I want to delete a comment with a specific ID but when I push the delete button it gives the error:

> exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"

The error is in the {routeCommentID} part of the next route:

```
Route::post('/deleteComment/{routeCommentID}', 'CommentController@delete');
```

What did I do wrong? Because when I remove that it works fine, but I need this part because I have to remove a comment with a specific ID.

Comment: what URL are you ending up hitting when you get that error?

Comment: can you add more details, check the navigator network inspector to see wich url are you calling with vueJS. Precise where you declared that route in laravel and if it is in a group ?

Comment: can u add your vue js code .?

Answer (score 0):

Run `php artisan route:list` and check if route like `'/deleteComment/{routeCommentID}'` exists and whether you use that route in your Vue application.

Answer (score -2):

for deleting a post it's better to use

```php
Route::delete('/deleteComment/{id}', 'CommentController@delete');
```

and checkout your blade for deletion
it should be something like below

```php
<form action={{ 'wanted route' }} method="post">
@csrf
@method('delete')
    // your code
</form>
```

Comment: Yea I know, but it is for VueJS not just laravel, so I can't use the @'s

Comment: @JensBouma you dont need the csrf if your route is in api.php

Comment: I think better approach is: `Route::delete('/comments/{Comment}/delete', 'CommentController@delete');`. Why? 1. Resource (rest) attitude. 2. You can use built in resource routing (`Route::resource()`). 3. You are aligned with Laravel docs. 4. Why not to allow laravel to bind model for you? :) | Check it here: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: @N69S I said something like, not exactly, in vue we have delete method in form